# Group by a list python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

I have the following list:

```
input=[(u'Number', u'Twenty', u'20.0'), (u'Number', u'five', u'5'), (u'fraction', u'one', u'1'), (u'fraction', u'in', u'/'), (u'fraction', u'five', u'5'), (u'Number', u'50 percent', u'50%')]<br>
```

I want to do a group by but with keeping same order. my desired output is:

```
[(u'Number', u'Twenty five', u'20.0 5'), (u'fraction', u'one in five', u'1 / 5'), (u'Number', u'50 percent', u'50%')]
```

I used the following code:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
for key, wordz in groupby(input, lambda t: t[0]):
    s=key,' '.join(item[1] for item in wordz)
    list1.append(s)

for key, wordz in groupby(input, lambda t: t[0]):
    s=' '.join(item[2] for item in wordz)
    list2.append(s)
result=zip(list1,list2)
print result
```

what i got is the following result:

```
[((u'Number', u'Twenty five'), u'20.0 5'), ((u'fraction', u'one in five'), u'1 / 5'), ((u'Number', u'50 percent'), u'50%')
```

Please can anyone guide me whether i should use something other than zip to get my desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After *grouping*, check on your group lengths to see which groups need modification (based on length), then *merge* non-duplicate words in the tuples in each group using `join`.

This does it:

```
inp = [(u'Number', u'Twenty', u'20.0'), (u'Number', u'five', u'5'), (u'fraction', u'one', u'1'), (u'fraction', u'in', u'/'), (u'fraction', u'five', u'5'), (u'Number', u'50 percent', u'50%')]

res = []
for i, g in groupby(inp, lambda t: t[0]):
    g = list(g)
    if len(g) > 1:
        g = [tuple(' '.join(i) if len(set(i)) > 1 else i[0] for i in zip(*g))]
    res.extend(g)

print(res)
# [('Number', 'Twenty five', '20.0 5'), ('fraction', 'one in five', '1 / 5'), ('Number', '50 percent', '50%')]
```

Try not to use a builtin as a name viz. `input`